# Buscar apenas uma parte aleatoria dentro de um código com select em mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, operador-like

O problema é o seguinte, eu tenho o código concatenado, preciso ver este código concatenado se parte dele se encontra na tabela, ou seja ao juntar **campo 1** e **campo 2** com PHP, antes de buscar na tabela, uma variável me traz isso pré-programada, eu terei o código:

```
212e5a8817f6f40da398b9baddddecd28abff2df24b6816fabdf2ff4e64dfd00b192d7f0a2bed8b0b7ab992312978885b4cd079a9d9ea5c955fce646635fa2e2n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73
```

eu tenho então este código, preciso colocar isso no `like` para ele me trazer este código os encontrando em dois campos diferentes, ou seja no **campo A** da minha tabela eu tenho

```
212e5a8817f6f40da398b9baddddecd28abff2df24b6816fabdf2ff4e64dfd00b192d7f0a2bed8b0
```

e no **campo B** eu tenho

```
b7ab992312978885b4cd079a9d9ea5c955fce646635fa2e2n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73
```

e na variável eu tenho

```
212e5a8817f6f40da398b9baddddecd28abff2df24b6816fabdf2ff4e64dfd00b192d7f0a2bed8b0b7ab992312978885b4cd079a9d9ea5c955fce646635fa2e2n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73
```

tenho que buscar isso no MySQL e me trazer estes dois campo, isso e possível?

**EDIT**

Achei, demorei mas achei
Básico com concat_ws

```
select * from tabela where concat_ws('',campo1,campo2) 
like '%n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73212e5a8817f6f40da398b9baddddecd28abff2df24b6816fabdf2ff4e64dfd00b192d7f0a2bed8b0b7ab992312978885b4c%';
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo da coluna?

Comment: @ricardo puts, acho que dei este mole entao, acho que élongtext, nao funciona se for longtext?

Comment: Vou conferir, como não sabia qual o tipo fiz para CHAR e VARCHAR, jaja edito minha resposta.

Comment: Editei minha resposta mas ainda não descobri se funciona com longtext

Comment: imaginei que isso funcionaria - select * from tabela where concat(campo1, campo2) like "%212e5a8817f6f40da398b9baddddecd28abff2df24b6816fabdf2ff4e64dfd00b192d7f0a2bed8b0b7ab992312978885b4cd079a9d9ea5c955fce646635fa2e2n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73%" - mas nao funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o tipo da coluna for: `CHAR` ou `VARCHAR` é certeza que o `LIKE` irá funcionar perfeitamente:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE campo LIKE “%n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73%”
```

Tente também usando a função para strings `INSTR`:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE INSTR("212e5a8817f6f40da398b9baddddecd28abff2df24b6816fabdf2ff4e64dfd00b192d7f0a2bed8b0b7ab992312978885b4cd079a9d9ea5c955fce646635fa2e2n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73", “%n3fbrqv345d4231qepklnt3i73%”);
```

Answer (score 0):

Verificou se o problema não é `case sensitive`?

Para resolver isso basta adicionar o `LOWER`, que vai transformar tudo em minúsculo.

```
$busca = strtolower($busca);
$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE LOWER(campo) LIKE '%". $busca . "%'");
```

Comment: não, é sem cases, é código aleatório com letras grandes e pequenas mesmo, mas acho que pode ser o fato de o falou ser longtext